# Deterministic finite automata uses

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata

I know how a dfa works but the only thing I'm confused is about it's use.

I've seen it's several applications on the internet like it is used in Traffic lights, in parser etc. but what is the exact point where it is used?

Like if I want to design a traffic light I would use counters, timers and the LEDs, where exactly is DFA?

Comment: How this s related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

The light is initially red then after certain time it becomes green or yellow based on some input signal. Considering the input signal t, the transition diagram for traffic signal will be as shown in fig Here the transition is based on two input parameter 1 and 0. If t = 1 then it jumps to the next state or continue in the same state for t = 0. FSM can model a huge no. of problems like automata, gesture recognition, networking design and artificial intelligence. ...this is the way how the exactly DFA used in traffic signals

[Here is the figure for the transition diagram for traffic signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akh43.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As DFA have a rich background in terms of the mathematical theory underlying their development it has wide application that we are used our daily life directly or indirectly, some of them are as follows;

Protocol analysis
Text parsing,
Video game character behavior,
Security analysis,
CPU control units,
Natural language processing
Speech recognition, etc.